# Download a image from angular

Tags: angular, codeigniter

In my angular 8 application , i have images . How to download the images in the angular application ?

In my application there is a listing , And in the listing there are images . I am using codeigniter as the backend . I want to know how to download the image from the angular application .

Answer (score 2):

Using the below code you can download the image from angular

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
a.download = title;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Also, using [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download) demo you can download the image

Answer (score 2):

You can use file-saver to do this task. I have compared the two methods and their benefits.

METHOD 1: This method will not work if you are dealing with image file. It just opens the image file in the browser tab.

TS

```
No changes needed
```

HTML

```
<img width="80" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<a class="btn btn-primary" [href]="https://picsum.photos/200/300" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

METHOD 2 (Suggested): This method will be helpful for all types of file.

Download the file-saver module first: `npm install file-saver`

TS

```
import { saveAs} from 'file-saver';
downloadImg(url,name){
  saveAs(url, name+'.png');
}
```

HTML

```
<img width="80" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<button (click)="downloadImg('https://picsum.photos/200/300','photo1')">Download</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('trident') > -1) { //For IE browser
  const byteCharacters = atob(base64String);
  const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'image/png' }); // change the file type accordingly
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "Image.png"); 
  }
} else { //For other browsers
  const linkSource = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64String;
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  const fileName = "Image.png";

  downloadLink.href = linkSource;
  downloadLink.download = fileName;
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **download attribute**

```
<a href="url" download>
  <img src="url" alt="">
</a>
```

IF your image is from amazon Bucket or something like that , then you need to configure download property while saving image on bucket .